# confused about parameters by value and by reference

Tags: c++

Assignment --

create a sample function that takes at least three parameters. At least one of the parameters should be passed by value, and at least two should be passed by reference.

I created the following but am confused if I am doing the right thing, I am confused about by value and by reference.

I set num1 = 30 in int but pass 7 to addThree is this considered by value?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//prototype
void addThree (int num1, int& num2, int& num3);

int main()
{
    int num1 = 30;
    int num2 = 50;
    int num3 = 80;

    addThree(7, num2, num3);

    return 0;
}

void addThree (int num1, int& num2, int& num3)
{

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    x = num1 + 3;
    y = num2 + 3;
    z = num3 + 3;

    cout << "x value is " << x << endl;
    cout << "y value is " << y << endl;
    cout << "z value is " << z << endl; 
}
```

prints out

x value is 10

y value is 53

z value is 83

Comment: smells like homework...

Comment: Technically you could comply with the assignment without having anything *in* either function or `main()`. Just create an empty function with three parameters, one by-value, two bye-reference. Done.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sounds like my minimalist approach to homework. An approach that always seems to work in computer science classes. Ha.

Answer (score 1):

There is no greate sense in your code because as I understand you have to demonstrate the difference between passing by value and passing by reference.

You can consider the code I will show as an idea for your code

```
#include <iostream>

void Multiply( int &x, int &y, int n )
{
   n /= 2;

   x *= n;
   y *= n;
}

int main()
{
   int x, y;
   int n;

   std::cout << "Enter x: ";
   std::cin >> x;

   std::cout << "Enter y: ";
   std::cin >> y;

   std::cout << "Enter factor: ";
   std::cin >> n;

   std::cout << "Before the multiplication. x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl;

   Myltiply( x, y, n );

   std::cout << "After  the multiplication. x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Add a modification to `n` in  `Multiply` that (obviously) doesn't change `n` in `main()` and I'll *quickly* up vote this as a good example of pass-by-reference ***vs.*** pass-by-value.

Comment: @WhozCraig I added a modification of n. :)

Answer (score 0):

By reference you are calling something by another name. By value you you take a copy

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't really know what you're asking, but here's a brief overview of pass by value, and pass by reference.

In C++, references are basically "safe" pointers. In Wikipedia they are defined as such:

> In the C++ programming language, a reference is a simple reference
>   datatype  that is less powerful but safer than the pointer type
>   inherited from C.

You declare references with an ampersand. You must specify an actual variable that the reference refers to.

```
int A = 5;   // Created an actual integer
int& rA = A; // Created a reference that refers to the integer I declared earlier
```

When, you pass something by reference into a function, you allow the function to modify the variable that the reference refers to. However, when you pass by value, the function creates it's own local-variable copy of the data you sent in. All changes to that local variable are  only present within the function's scope.

This is better seen than said. Observe.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int& ra = a;

    std::cout << a;    // Ouput: 5
    plus(&a);
    std::cout << a;    // Ouput: 6

    return 0;
}

void plus (int& num)
{
    num++;
    std::cout << num;      // Ouput: 6
}
```

Notice how when we passed by reference, `a` in `main()` was changed. If we just passed by value, this would happen:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int& ra = a;

    std::cout << a;    // Ouput: 5
    plus(a);
    std::cout << a;    // Ouput: 5

    return 0;
}

void plus (int num)
{
    num++;
    std::cout << num;      // Ouput: 6
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pass By value**

C always passes arguments `by value`: a copy of the value of each argument is passed to the function; the function cannot modify the actual argument passed to it.

As in your program the function `void addThree (int num1, int& num2, int& num3)` has a parameter `int num1` which is passed by value.

That means, When the function is called some byte of memory is allocated in the `addThree` functions stack frame  and the value at the time of calling i.e. Form statement `addThree(7, num2, num3);` value `7` is passed in that memory of `int num1`.

Where as,
In `pass by reference`, No memory is allocated to the variable `num2 & num3` they will point to the same address as `int num2 & num2` in `main()` functions stack frame.

As per your program,

```
x = num1 + 3; // here num 1 is form function addThree () so num1 = 7 and so 7+3 = 10
y = num2 + 3; // here num2  has same address as in the main's num2 so num2= 50, 50+3 = 53
z = num3 + 3;//  here num3  has same address as in the main's num3 so num3= 50, 80+3 = 83
```

Hope this will help you to understand the concept of `By reference and By value`

Comment: wasn't sure if it was considered by value if i declared num 1 = 10 but then passed 7 into the function

Comment: @Jessica if you use `addThree(num1, num2, num3);` then the value of `num1` in `addThree` will be `10 for num1 = 10 in main`

Answer (score 0):

Your addThree function is correct to be of the form "addThree(int num1, int& num2, int& num3)" but just by setting your parameters like that already makes it pass by value for num1 and the others by reference.

"int num1" means "make a new int and give it num1's value, then send that to the function", while "int& num1" would mean here's my num1, but whatever you do to it inside the function also changes it outside the function.

So you didn't need to pass in 7, you could've just said addThree(num1, num2, num3) and you'd be right, try running this version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    void addThree(int num1, int& num2, int& num3);

    int num1 = 30;
    int num2 = 50;
    int num3 = 80;

    addThree(num1, num2, num3);

    cout << "now, back in main num1 is: " << num1 << endl;
    cout << "now, back in main num2 is: " << num2 << endl;
    cout << "now, back in main num3 is: " << num3 << endl;

    int pause; //just to keep the window open
    cin >> pause; //just to keep the window open
    return 0;
}

void addThree(int num1, int& num2, int& num3) {
     num1 = num1 + 3;
     num2 = num2 + 3;
     num3 = num3 + 3;

     cout << "inside function, num1 is: " << num1 << endl;
     cout << "inside function, num2 is: " << num2 << endl;
     cout << "inside function, num3 is: " << num3 << endl;
}
```

Notice that num1, which was passed by value (due to using "int num1" instead of "int& num1"), was the only int that the function didn't have lasting effects on.

Comment: TY!, that is exactly what I was looking for a print out before and after so I can see the change.